# showing progress bar during network call

Tags: android

I want to show the progress bar during web service call. I called progress bar before calling the service, but it is being called after the service call is finished and i have received the response.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LogIn.this,"","Loading. Please wait...", true);

 status=Loginvalid(method,username,psword); //calling the method for making service call
```

But, progress dialog is starting after the response is received from the service.
Please how can i fix this problem..

Comment: Thanks everybody...My problem is solved using AsyncTask. To pass the context, i created a setter method in my subclass of AsyncTask and also provided a constructor. So from my activity class, i called the setter first and then the execute() method. Its working fine now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public class Progress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {



        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(MyActivity.this, "Loading.. Wait..");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    // do your network connection

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss(); 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AsyncTask`. It is the most effective and painless way of showing a progress dialog during a web service call.

show the progressbar on preexecute, call your webservice in doInBackground method, and dismiss the progressbar onPostexecute.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly show the progress dialog it must be executed on UIThread, while all the other work(`service call`) - in another. See the example [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).